# Printing a local file on Android via Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to use the print dialog via Forms. I have found an solution on iOS but the android implementation is giving me problems.

As far as i can see it is not possible to call the Android print manager and parse a file to it. 
It can only be a Android.Views.View, is that true?
To do that would be my ideal solution.

I have tried to convert my content (A webview showing a local pdf) to this android view but this seems also not really to work but i am out off my depths here.

in the code below i try to convert a forms.webview to an android.view and then parse it to the print manager.
This produce the print dialog but with a black white page.

```
var size = new Rectangle(webview.X, webview.Y, webview.Width, webview.Height);
var vRenderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer(webview);
var viewGroup = vRenderer.ViewGroup;
vRenderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout();
var layoutParams = new Android.Views.ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
viewGroup.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
webview.Layout(size);
viewGroup.Layout(0, 0, (int)webview.WidthRequest, (int)webview.HeightRequest);

var printMgr = (Android.Print.PrintManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.PrintService);
var docAdt = new Droid.GenericPrintAdapter(Forms.Context, viewGroup);

printMgr.Print("test", docAdt, null);
```

The next is the "GenericPrintAdapter"

```
public class GenericPrintAdapter : PrintDocumentAdapter
{
    View view;
    Context context;
    PrintedPdfDocument document;
    float scale;

    public GenericPrintAdapter(Context context, View view)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public override void OnLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                                   CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras)
    {
        document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);

        CalculateScale(newAttributes);

        var printInfo = new PrintDocumentInfo
            .Builder("MyPrint.pdf")
            .SetContentType(PrintContentType.Document)
            .SetPageCount(1)
            .Build();

        callback.OnLayoutFinished(printInfo, true);
    }

    void CalculateScale(PrintAttributes newAttributes)
    {
        int dpi = Math.Max(newAttributes.GetResolution().HorizontalDpi, newAttributes.GetResolution().VerticalDpi);

        int leftMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.LeftMils / 1000);
        int rightMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.RightMils / 1000);
        int topMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.TopMils / 1000);
        int bottomMargin = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.MinMargins.BottomMils / 1000);

        int w = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.GetMediaSize().WidthMils / 1000) - leftMargin - rightMargin;
        int h = (int)(dpi * (float)newAttributes.GetMediaSize().HeightMils / 1000) - topMargin - bottomMargin;

        scale = Math.Min((float)document.PageContentRect.Width() / w, (float)document.PageContentRect.Height() / h);
    }

    public override void OnWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                                  CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback)
    {
        PrintedPdfDocument.Page page = document.StartPage(0);

        page.Canvas.Scale(scale, scale);

        view.Draw(page.Canvas);

        document.FinishPage(page);

        WritePrintedPdfDoc(destination);

        document.Close();

        document.Dispose();

        callback.OnWriteFinished(pages);
    }

    void WritePrintedPdfDoc(ParcelFileDescriptor destination)
    {
        var javaStream = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(destination.FileDescriptor);
        var osi = new OutputStreamInvoker(javaStream);
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            document.WriteTo(mem);
            var bytes = mem.ToArray();
            osi.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `WebView` contains a method called `CreatePrintDocumentAdapter` that returns a `PrintDocumentAdapter` that is then passed to the `PrintManager` instance.

Comment: @SushiHangover thats the Native Android WebView :( The Xamarin.Forms WebView does not have that, since its a android only thing. Do you know off a way to convert the forms to a native?

Comment: You will need to the access the native `WebView` control, there are multiple  options... You could expose the `native` control via a custom renderer and pass that to a dependency service, embed the native printing routine in the native renderer itself, or have a dependency service iterate through all the child views in the current `Activity` (GetChildCount/GetChildAt/...) to find your native android `WebView` and then call `CreatePrintDocumentAdapter`, etc...

Comment: i am so confused. 
something like a `public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>` and then what? 

Its a SharedCode project so getting the current android activity is not the most simple thing in the world.
On what object would you call the GetChildCount/GetChildAt functions?

Comment: If you are writing a custom WebViewRenderer then you already have access to the Android WebView so you do not have iterate the views on the  current Activity, you would call the CreatePrintDocumentAdapter method on the native view within your renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now a "working" solution.

This gets the current Android.Webkir.WebView and create the printAdapter from that.

Thanks to @SushiHangover for pointing me in the right direction.

Its a bit of a hack but works for my needs.

If anyone else ever needs this i have included both the Android and iOS code.

```
#if __ANDROID__
            var vRenderer = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.GetRenderer(webview);
            var viewGroup = vRenderer.ViewGroup;

            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                if (viewGroup.GetChildAt(i).GetType().Name == "WebView")
                {
                    var AndroidWebView = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i) as Android.Webkit.WebView;
                    var tmp = AndroidWebView.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter("print");
                    var printMgr = (Android.Print.PrintManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.PrintService);
                    printMgr.Print("print", tmp, null);
                    break;
                }
            }
#elif __IOS__
            var printInfo = UIKit.UIPrintInfo.PrintInfo;
            printInfo.Duplex = UIKit.UIPrintInfoDuplex.LongEdge;
            printInfo.OutputType = UIKit.UIPrintInfoOutputType.General;
            printInfo.JobName = "AppPrint";
            var printer = UIKit.UIPrintInteractionController.SharedPrintController;
            printer.PrintInfo = printInfo;
            printer.PrintingItem = Foundation.NSData.FromFile(pdfPath);
            printer.ShowsPageRange = true;
            printer.Present(true, (handler, completed, err) =>
            {
                if (!completed && err != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Printer Error");
                }
            });
#endif
```